# How do I get Vimwiki links to display as underlined instead of default brackets [[]]?

Tags: vim

When looking at a the Vimwiki docs, I see this image 
[image: desired link style]

which shows a Vimwiki link as underlined.

But when I make a link using [[linktosomething]], it shows up with the brackets. It still works as expected, but how do I change the style.

Mine looks like this:

[image: my link]

In the Vimwiki docs I set the .vimrc to include the typical:

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Is this an issue with Vimwiki syntax vs markdown syntax? Im confused about how to get the desired link styling

Comment: Sometime, such a Vim-specific question finds in [vi.stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) a better place to live in.

Comment: You may need to check the option conceallevel. The underline may well be a syntax thing though

Answer (score 1):

As D. Ben Knoble said, it seems like you need a build of Vim with the `conceal` option enabled. According to mediapathic in [this article](https://groups.google.com/g/vimwiki/c/_0tDK08efEM/m/wEt1Wjl6C_oJ), macOS' own Vim build doesn't have it, whereas MacVim's does.

Launching Vimwiki with MacVim you get the brackets hidden by default. If you tried to query the status of `conceallevel` using `:set conceallevel?`, you get `2`, instead of `E519: Option not supported: conceallevel?` in macOS' built-in vim.

Although I haven't tried myself, but you can also try building vim from its source with the `+conceal` option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it yourself by adding the following line to your vimrc:

```
hi VimwikiLink term=underline ctermfg=cyan guifg=cyan gui=underline
```

Here I have changed my color to cyan and have added underline.